# jquery customizing dialog buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

[image]I am using jquery dialog with query ui 1.8.7.custom.min.js

I need to customize the buttons on the the dialog and the location where they show up on the dialog. I was able for the most part to customize my dialog box but customizing buttons and its location had been tough cookie so far.
Please find screen shots and code below

```
HTML:

<style>
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-content {
 border:1px solid #cde68c;
 border-bottom:0px;
 background-color: white !important;
 color: #333;
 font: 12px/180% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
 display:none;
}
#ui-dialog-title-dialog {
 color: yellow !important;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
 border:1px solid #cde68c;
 border-top:0px;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}

</style>
        <div id="dialog">
            <p><span id="emailNotice"></span></p>
        </div>

Javascript:

$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j('#dialog').dialog('open');
    $j('#emailNotice').html('show some notice text abcd');  

    $j('#dialog').dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                className: 'cancelButtonClass',
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I want to be able to position buttons left , right , top / bottom etc

Comment: one thing i noticed inside of your `"Cancel"` function: you have `className: 'cancelButtonClass',`. That won't do anything. I'm not sure the easiest way to add a custom class to that button, but I do know that there are existing classes on there that you can target with your css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass an empty object for the `buttons` property. You would then add your buttons directly in your "dialog" div. Of course, this would mean you'd have to handle the button click events manually.

**Rough example:**

```
<div id="dialog">
  <p><span id="emailNotice"></span></p>
  <button id="myButton">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$j('#dialog').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {}
    }
});
```

Comment: howd I make the ok and close button then? Howd I pass the actions in this case to them?

Comment: nm...got it... $j('#yesButton').click(function(){
  //alert('hi');
  $j('#dialog').dialog('close');
 });

Answer (score 2):

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
buttons: [
       {

            text: "Delete that",
            className: 'deleteButtonClass',
            click: function() {
                alert('foobar');                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Find in jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css the class bellow and remove `float: right;`

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
float: right;
}
```

Tested in jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css not in jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are seeking, but I have fully given up trying to configure the JQuery UI dialog buttons. They are a hot mess to work with.

So I end up using my own custom HTML fragments where I can style a button any way I please using normal HTML and CSS. Buttons float:left, some float:right. I can use Font Awesome to put fantastic looking icons on the buttons, etc.

It takes a little bit of doing, but not nearly so much as pulling out your last remaining hair trying to finagle JQuery UI dialog.

Basically, it's done in 3 steps:

1. Configure the dialog.
   Basically a straight-forward $( "selector" ).dialog( ... );
2. Load up an HTML fragment.
   I have a folder of "html fragments" where I create either a few lines or complex forms. Then at runtime I use $.get() to load those fragments and do a $( "dialog" ).parent.append( fragment );
3. Find the button(s) and configure them.
   After it has been appended to the parent, find each button you need to configure: $( "button1" ).button( ... ).click( ... );

   ```
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( ... );

    // -------------------------------------    
    // Get the button fragment and append to the dialog
    $.get
    (
        "/path/to/fragment/buttons.frag.html"
        , function( frag )
        {
            // Fragment appended to the dialog's parent.
            $( "#dialog" ).parent().append( frag );

            // Config the button
            $( "#button1" ).button().click
            (
                function()
                {
                    // do something here
                }
            );
        }
    );
   ```